# Online Courses to Learn Writing Custom Python Scripts / Plugins in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-python-console

I am looking for resources to learn writing Python Scripts / Plugins for QGIS. The Developer Cookbook is a good start, but I am specifically looking for a video-based resource that teaches with hands-on exercises.

Comment: List compilation requests are off-topic for the Focused question/Best answer model used in GIS SE. This would be appropriate in [chat], but Chat is *underutilized* (a ghost town).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a  couple of videos on the internet but they may not be structured as a course. I found this course on Udemy though which is pretty basic and most importantly free:

https://www.udemy.com/course/introduction-to-developing-qgis-python-plugins/

It teaches how to create plug-in but includes some python learning skills as well.

In my opinion, you should start here: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ ; it is not a video but it is a great way to learn as well.